# How to fix "non-numeric argument to binary operator“

Tags: r

I want to dra a waterfall plot and actually I have successfully get a good plot. Then I want to add a binary column using ifelse function. Now the function does not work, and says "non-numeric argument...". Can anyone help me? Thanks！

```
library(tumgr) 
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
tumorgrowth = sampleData
tumorgrowth = do.call(rbind,
by(tumorgrowth, tumorgrowth$name,
     function(subset) within(subset,
              { treatment = ifelse(rbinom(1,1,0.5), "Drug","Control")   
#random classfied
                o = order(date)
                date = date[o]
                size = size[o]
                baseline = size[1]
                percentChange = 100*(size-baseline)/baseline
                time = ifelse(date > 250, 250, date)                    
                cstatus = factor(ifelse(date > 250, 0, 1))
              })))
 tumorgrowth1 = tumorgrowth%>%
   group_by(name)%>%
   mutate(patient=percentChange[which.max(abs(percentChange))])%>%
   select(name,patient,cstatus)
o=order(tumorgrowth1$patient,decreasing = TRUE)
tumorgrowth1=tumorgrowth1[o,]
tumorgrowth1=distinct(tumorgrowth1)

col=ifelse(tumorgrowth1$cstatus==0, "#BC5A42", "#009296")

# This function does not work after adding the "col" column
waterfall=function(data,var){
  barplot(data[,var],width=0.1,col=col, border=col,cex.axis=1.2, 
  cex.lab=1.4)
}
waterfall(tumorgrowth1,"patient")
```

Comment: `"BC5A42"` is missing the `#` in front. It isn't a valid color without it.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it's my mistake when copy.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. For the `barplot` you need the matrix to be transposed which can be achieved with `t()`. Since `cstatus` is a factor column, this step would transform all data into `"character"`. Probably the column is not needed so we can fix this by simply excluding it. Naturally in your function you'll have to move `var` to the rows.

```
waterfall <- function(data,var) {
  barplot(data[var, ], width=0.1, col=col, border=col, cex.axis=1.2, 
          cex.lab=1.4)
}
waterfall(t(tumorgrowth1[-3]), "patient")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and it does work! But I don't quite understand what does t(tumorgraph1[-3]) mean, and why do you use data[var,] instead data[,var]?

Comment: @JohnSun Compare `tumorgrowth1; t(tumorgrowth1); tumorgrowth1[, "patient"]; t(tumorgrowth1)[, "patient"]; t(tumorgrowth1)["patient", ]
`.